# I am trying to run a project based on gesture recognition and my iOS simulator says front camera not found

Tags: swift, computer-vision, ios-simulator, gesture-recognition

[This is the image showing a simulator with a popup denoting a message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMZol.jpg)

I am trying to run a swift project on Xcode Version 12.0 beta 5 (12A8189h). I am attaching the  link from where I have downloaded the project. It is based on gesture recognition using Computer Vision. When I try to run the project a popup comes on the simulator mentioning that the front camera could not be found. What can I do further?

P.S. The link of the screenshot of the picture is attached.

Link of the screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMZol.jpg

Link of the project - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_hand_poses_with_vision

Comment: Make sure you set a value for the Privacy - Camera Usage Description key in your Info.plist file when requesting camera access.

Comment: I'm not sure we can launch the camera from the simulator. Try on a real device

Comment: @ShivamParmar Oh, I didn't look at that. I will check that and then proceed. Thank you!

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen I don't have a real device and that is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a real device for test your case

Comment: @seoyaz, I don't have a real device.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set a value for the `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` key in your `Info.plist` file when requesting camera access.